# How can I save variables in awk?

Tags: awk

How can I print the filename and the result of `1/2*(a+b)`, where `a` is the 1st field of the 2nd line and `b` is the 1st field of the last line please? I do not know how to save the values into variables as constants. Many thanks

```
awk -v a=$(NR==2{print $1}) b=$(END(print $1)) '{print FILENAME, 1/2*(a+b)}' rv*.out
```

file1

```
4 5 6
14545.5886 2 6
2 3 5
45457.5462 8 6
```

file2

```
1 2 
34441.4545 8
6 8
8 8 
54447.4545 1
```

Output for:

```
for file in test1.txt test2.txt; do 
    awk ' (NR==2){a=$1} END{print FILENAME, 1/2*(a+$1)}' "$file" >> stredni.txt; 
done

test1.txt 7272.79
test2.txt 17220.7
```

Desired result:

```
test1 30001.5674
test2 44444.4545
```

Comment: Thanks. I made an edit that should help clarify, please let me know if that is not what you meant. And can you please explain what you want to store in variables? What kind of variables? Where would you use these variables? In the same awk script? In a different command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for i in  "p.txt" "l.txt"; do co=`wc -l $i| awk '{print $1}'`; awk -v co="$co" 'NR==2{a=$1}NR==co{b=$1}END{print FILENAME,1/2*(a+b)}' $i; done
```

output

```
p.txt 30001.6
l.txt 44444.5
```

Answer (score 6):

The syntax `var=$(something)` is shell syntax (and not `awk`) which means "run the command `something` and store the result in the shell variable `$var`". You seem to be expecting it to be somehow linked to your `awk` script since `NR==2` etc are awk statements. That won't work.

This command will print the output you expect:

```
$ for file in file1 file2; do 
    awk ' (NR==2){a=$1} END{print FILENAME, 1/2*(a+$1)}' "$file"; 
  done
file1 30001.6
file2 44444.5
```

You can do it using GNU `awk` (`gawk`) also:

```
$ gawk 'FNR==2{a=$1}ENDFILE{print FILENAME, 1/2*(a+$1)}' file1 file2
file1 30001.6
file2 44444.5
```

Comment: How is it with decimal places? I have four decimal places in 1st column, but the result give only one or zero.

Comment: @ElenaGreg first, please make sure that the examples you give accurately represent your data. That said, this should work fine with decimals, that isn't a problem. If this doesn't work, then please edit your question and add an actual example file and the command you ran and the output you got. Are the decimals maybe `0`?

Comment: I edited the question. Thank you

Comment: @ElenaGreg I just ran the exact commands from your question (and my answer) and got the expected result (see updated answer). If you run this on _the exact example files_ you give in your question do you not get the result I show?

Comment: I got file1.txt 7272.79
file2.txt 17220.7. I copied your answer and used files from my question.  I have no idea what is wrong.

Comment: @ElenaGreg that is very strange. If possible, try posting one of the actual files somewhere. Also, what operating system are you using?

Comment: The value of `$1` (or `$0` or any other field) in the END section is undefined by POSIX. In some awks (e.g. gawk) it'll be the value it had when the last record was read, in other awks (apparently whichever one the OP is using) it'll be null, and in others still it could be anything else. For portability to all awks you need `awk 'NR==2{a=$1} {b=$1} END{print FILENAME, 1/2*(a+b)}' "$file"`

Comment: I uploaded the files: http://leteckaposta.cz/687713493 The command you wrote works the same. I use "Linux Mint"
VERSION="19.2 (Tina)"

Comment: I will do that manually, I need to apply this to only 28 files.

Comment: @ElenaGreg please also try Ed's version: `awk 'NR==2{a=$1} {b=$1} END{print FILENAME, 1/2*(a+b)}' "$file"` does that work better?

Comment: Ed's command gives the same (wrong) result

Comment: @ElenaGreg what operating system are you using? Please edit your question and add that information and also show us the output of `locale`. Also show us the output of running this: `LC_ALL=C awk 'NR==2{a=$1} {b=$1} END{print FILENAME, 1/2*(a+b)}' test1.txt test2.txt`.

Comment: Try adding `!NF{next}` as the first line of the script as the only way I can imagine the script I provided not doing what you want would be if you had blank lines in the input file so adding that code would skip them. If that still doesn't work then change it to `awk '!NF{next} NR==2{a=$1} {b=$1} {print FILENAME, NR, $0, "["a":"b"]"} END{print FILENAME, 1/2*(a+b)}' "$file" | cat -Ev` and then edit your question to show the output you get from that plus the output you get from `cat -Ev "$file"`.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works.